# Is there way to fix CSV reading in Russian Language in Azure ML Studio?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a large csv file containing some text in Russian language. When I upload it to Azure ML Studio as dataset, it appears like "����". What I can do to fix that problem?

I tried changing encoding of my text to UTF8, KOI8-R.

There is no code, but I can share part of the dataset for you to try.

Comment: Please post some CSV data for testing. Thanks!

Comment: Did any of the answer actually solve your issue? Please mark the correct answer as solved or leave a comment if you are still facing some issues thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution worked out.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround may be zipping your csv and reading it using python module. Your python script in this case should look something like :

```py
# coding: utf-8

# The script MUST contain a function named azureml_main
# which is the entry point for this module.

# imports up here can be used to 
import pandas as pd

# The entry point function can contain up to two input arguments:
#   Param<dataframe1>: a pandas.DataFrame
#   Param<dataframe2>: a pandas.DataFrame
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):

    russian_ds = pd.read_csv('./Script Bundle/your_russian_dataset.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')

    # your logic goes here
    return russian_ds
```

It worked for with french datasets so hopefully you will find it useful